# Can i get more than 2 bytes from iBeacon using AltBeacon lib?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

The question is, how i can get the manufecturer data that is Int type. Device send me a packet like - https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/201492492-iBeacon-advertising-packet-structure, so as i understand there are 4 bytes for manufecturer data, but the lib could parse only 2 bytes value - 0xFF
 Using altbeacon library on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the format listed in the linked document, you can access the first two bytes of what it calls "manufacturer data" with:

```
beacon.getManufacturer()
```

and the second two bytes with

```
beacon.getBeaconTypeCode()
```

Strictly speaking, *all* of the bytes of the beacon advertisement are manufacturer data, so the referenced document referring to only four bytes as "manufacturer data" is a bit misleading.  The method names above divide these four bytes into the two fields above because this is their standard usage when working with bluetooth beacons.